# iOS- Adhoc Builds with Distribution Certification Push notification comes twice

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my iOS application, I have implemented Push Notification. All working fine except some time push comes twice.

I am using Adhoc Builds with Distribution certificate. In Back-end we send request to APNS only once. Also, we request APNS Production server for any calls

I have googled it but didn't find any solution. Can any one confirm me if this is iOS bug or not.

Also, this is random behavior. As about 80% of time I get two notifications for single event.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have two different tokens registered for the same device, which causes the server to send the notification twice (one for each token, resulting in two messages being sent to the same device).

Push tokens don't usually change, but they can. This can be a result of re-installing the app, changes in the operating system or any other consideration not fully disclosed to us as the app's developers. That is why Apple indicates that you need to send the most updated version of the token whenever the app is launched.

In your case, it's possible that the token changed for some reason and even though you are sending the notification once for each token, you are sending it once to each of the two tokens representing that device. The explanation for why you're only receiving double messages 80% of the time, is that in the remaining 20%, the messages are sent so close to one another that the operating system (or Apple's servers) are blocking them and only sending one.

Can that be the case?

Comment: I think that can be a case because I have installed the iOS build multiple times as its in progress. So have to create multiple Adhoc builds. Just want to ask a ques here. Do older device token are still valid in this case if Device token is changed?

Comment: That's actually a great question. The old tokens shouldn't be valid anymore (although it's possible that they still are, especially in non-appStore environments). However, you may have the same token registered for different users (one that logged out in the past) or any other scenario in which you think you're sending one push notification each, but actually resulting in sending to the same device twice. I would recommend clearing all push data related to these devices/users from the DB, re-registering the device and trying again.

Comment: Finally the issue is with the backend.. Backend guy is sending pushes for two times in thats why i recd pushes twice.. ooops silly mistake.